# How can I handle a submitted form?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a strong typed view from a model class. I would like to add there a text field where I can pass a number. This number should told the controller, how often the object should be added to the database. But in the View I only have the submit button and my controller function handles this postback

```
' POST: /Adminpanel/AddHardware '
<Authorize()>
<HttpPost>
Function AddHardware(ByVal hw As Hardware) As ActionResult
    If ModelState.IsValid Then
        db.Hardware.Add(hw)
        db.SaveChanges()
        Response.Redirect("~/Adminpanel/Hardware")
    Else
        Response.Redirect("~/Adminpanel/Hardware")
    End If
End Function
```

it should be look like:

```
' POST: /Adminpanel/AddHardware '
<Authorize()>
<HttpPost>
Function AddHardware(ByVal hw As Hardware, ByVal amount As Integer) As ActionResult
    If ModelState.IsValid Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To amount
            db.Hardware.Add(hw)
            db.SaveChanges()
        Next
        Response.Redirect("~/Adminpanel/Hardware")
    Else
        Response.Redirect("~/Adminpanel/Hardware")
    End If
End Function
```

How can I add this text field in my view and pass the value to the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a input element in your view (inside your form) and give it name="amount". And when the form is submitted MVC will automatically bind the value from view to your controller. You can access the value of `amount` in controller directly.

NOTE: The binding depends on the name of the element. If your input tag has the name `amount` and in your controller parameters if you have a parameter `amount` MVC will bind the value to this parameter. So always make sure your `element name` and the `parameter name` are the same.

Comment: No problem, But make sure you use models to send and receive values. If there is only one or two odd parameters to be passed then you can use the above approach, But this is a bad practice if you are dealing with more than 2 parameters. Use Models which keeps your programming clean and tidy.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply add an `<input ... />` to your form with an **id** of **amount**, and MVC will take care of binding the value to your `amount` parameter.